# Is there such thing as a groovy xml-rpc request builder?

Tags: grails, groovy, xml-rpc

I'm trying to send a request to another webapp that uses xml-rpc. So far, I've already added groovy's [XML-RPC module](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a_6dVlgQzFEUJ%3agroovy.codehaus.org/XMLRPC%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ph) into my project. I'm quite stomped to be honest because the examples I see on the internet are sparse. I just wanna know quick if my line of thought is correct. So here are the questions:

1. If I wanted to send an object along with my request, this means I'll have to transform that object into an xml format as explained [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_request.htm), is that correct?
2. If the answer in #1 is yes, is there like a groovy way to transform an object into the said format in #1?

My object looks like this when rendered as an XML. It's not the proper format I know, but I was looking for something that will transform it as explained in #2's link. Much help pointing me to the right path is appreciated.

```
<myObject id="1">
   <date>2014-07-01 00:00:00.0 PHT</date>
   <isCancelled>true</isCancelled>
   <isPosted>true</isPosted>
   <isReceived>false</isReceived>
   <issueTo>some bloke</issueTo>
   <items>
      <item id="1" />
      <item id="2" />
   </items>
</myObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really know what you want then you can write your own marshaller with your custom XML-generation.

```
@Log4j
class YourCustomMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<XML> {

    @Override
    boolean supports(Object object) {
        return object instanceof YourCustomDomain
    }

    @Override
    void marshalObject(Object object, XML converter) throws ConverterException {
        ...
    }
}
```

And register it in the `BootStrap.groovy` init section.

```
import grails.converters.JSON
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        ...
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(new YourCustomMarshaller())
        ...
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Also, you can try to search the plugin. For example like this
`https://grails.org/plugins/search?q=rpc`

The first link is `http://grails.org/plugin/xmlrpc` but I'm not sure that is what you need.

Comment: I tried using it, but no luck. It fails to download dependencies. And also it's quite old, the last update was 2007.. :(

Comment: You may look at plugin sources and if it fully fits your needs then you may patch it and adapt for yourself.
I don't think that is too difficult.